# Lighttpd Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I have an issue with Lighttpd Rewrite and static files.

Here is my rewrite syntax:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.*)\.(php|css|js|jpg|png)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)$" => "/router.php?url=$1"
)
```

All .css and .js files load up just fine but no images load up. I have attempted check if the file is being served from /images but that does not fix the issue. I checked the access logs and all css and js files have a 200 status but all image files have a 404. The paths are correct.

Does anyone have an idea why the .css and .js files would load properly but images do not.

Comment: Do images work if you disable rewriting? Pardon if it's a dumb question, but it's the first thing I'd try. If images still don't work after disabling rewriting, then you likely have something wrong at a level beyond Lighttpd - such as file system permissions. (Remember that you have to restart the Lighty daemon after changing config files.)

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried to remove the leading "/", or make it optional like this:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/?(.*)\.(php|css|js|jpg|png)$" => "$0",
    "^/?(.+)$" => "/router.php?url=$1"
)
```

Additionally, you should use `url.rewrite-once` and may - if your lighttpd is > 1.4.24 - use `url.rewrite-if-not-file`, which makes life a lot easier with existing files like CSS, JS and images.

See [Lighty-Docs on mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModRewrite)

Answer (score 0):

`url.rewrite-if-not-file` was very helpfull in my vbulletin - vbseo lighttpd rewrite problem. Also I think it speeds up the comparing process while rewrite module running in lighttpd.

Comment: Anyone verify that this does indeed "speeds up comparing process" ?